# Where is the source code of the PHP SPL library?

Tags: php, spl

I can find the definition files at `http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/...` but I want to extend [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/DirectoryIterator) and [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo) to work over a virtual file-system stored on a database *not* a real file-system.

Comment: Is it not included in the big PHP source package?

Comment: I guess it have to be if you compile your php interpreter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

- [On php.net](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=tree;f=ext/spl)
- and, [on Github](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/spl)